# Centering elements when resizing windows in VB6

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, maximize

I'm building an application in VB6 where the standard form size is 1024x768, for the older monitors that will see it. Some of the users will, however, have higher resolutions available, and I'd like the program to still look nice when they maximize the screen. I don't want to resize the elements on the form at all, but I am looking to recenter everything. There are two options as I see it, and I don't really like either one:

- The _real_ way, writing dynamic code that'll place each element on the form in relation to other elements, so that no matter what size it is, they'll always recenter properly.
- The easier but cheesier way, to put all the elements in a 1024x768 PictureBox and just center that on the screen whenever the form is resized.

I don't love the first one because ugh, and I don't love the second one because it's such an ad hoc solution. Also, while I like the idea behind the first one more, it has the problem of permanence: if I need to go back and change some elements, I'm then stuck rewriting lots of repositioning code. And the second one has a sorta similar issue, that I'd lose one of the nice things that VB6 does provide: being able to see the grid structure of the form.

Anyone know of any magic solutions?

I'm currently leaning towards the PictureBox, just because the prospect of writing and undoubtedly rewriting all that positioning code is depressing. The issue here then is that I already have these 50+ elements on the form, but I'd need them to be in the PictureBox. I can copy and paste without creating the array it always seems to want to make, but then I'd have to go through an rename them all... so my second question, is there any simple way to transfer a preexisting element on a form into a PictureBox?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Honestly, the second solution you described isn't ad hoc - it is organized.  UI is all about containers.  When you design a UI you group clumps of related items; the metaphor is cleanly applied to implementation of that UI as well.  I think what is throwing you for a loop is that you are misusing PictureBox.  Lemmie look and see if there are VB6 elements designed for grouping controls...

Comment: Neither option actually improves the user interface.  There will just be larger bands of battleship gray, there isn't actually more detail to look at.  Like a list box that doesn't need scrolling so often or a grid that shows more rows.  As long as you are contemplating this, just do nothing.  Those bands of gray might just as well live on the right and bottom.

Comment: I'd just disallow maximize and probably control the range of sizing in the Resize event. If you insist on this goofy "maximize and center" thing use a UserControl instead of a PictureBox. You can select all of the controls using Shift for extended selection or "lasso" them using the mouse, then cut and paste into your container of choice.

Comment: @Hans Passant - I'm a symmetrical kind of guy. I'd rather have nice even swaths of boring.  

@Bob Riemersma - I don't think it's insanely goofy to allow someone to maximize a window and have the objects center themselves... it's not necessary, no, but sometimes it's just nice to have a maximized window. But with the cutting and pasting... boy do I feel like a moron. *facepalm* I forgot that cutting existed, I was so focused on trying to get around the array creation when copying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no free lunch. If you want your VB6 application to "look nice" when resized, you **have** to write the dynamic sizing logic in the `Form_Resize` event. Otherwise, as others have stated, you'll have large gray areas with everything crammed in the upper left corner. Centering in a `PictureBox` isn't much better. Either way, it will look non-standard and amateurish.

I've written this type of code for several VB6 applications. I'll agree that it's a little tiresome to write, but it's not difficult. You just have to think about:

- Button positioning - The lower right coordinates of your form will change, and buttons are usually placed along the right side, or relative to the lower-right corner.
- Display control resizing - You can widen listboxes, multi-line textboxes, dropdown lists, etc.  Your code can decide if these should be a percentage of the form's new width/height, or should expand to fill what's left after you've positioned everything else.  I think the latter approach works better, but it depends on the application.
- The margin between the controls and the edges of the form, as well as the margin between the controls themselves. I define a value named "Gutter" to hold this value, then apply it as necessary when positioning, say, a series of buttons horizontally relative to the lower right corner.
- Don't ***resize*** buttons or labels, just ***reposition*** them.
- Don't resize fonts.

"Anchor" type properties make this type of code unnecessary in VB.NET. If you think about that for a minute, you'll see that if a few properties can handle this logic, the lines of code needed to do the same can't be all that complex.  Once you have the first control positioned and sized, you can base other controls positions off that control's top, left, width, and height, and just walk your way across the form.

When you get it right, I think you will find that it actually is worth the effort.

Comment: I was hoping the free lunch might come in the form of the "Anchor" properties, but I guess no luck on that end with this older version of the software. This actually totally answered my question, that there is no magic solution. Thanks JeffK.

Comment: Resizing logic seems to always scare people, but it's really not that big a deal. Start at the top left, and bottom right, set controls to their appropriate sizes using the positioning of controls that are immediately above/to the left, and below/to the right of them. Work you're way toward the middle (where there's usually one main grid/listbox/multiline textbox, and done. Sure, it's a few lines of code, but it's not a big deal. Create a few consts to set pad sizes of 8-12 pixels (or the equivalent twips) to make it a little easier.

Comment: One important optimization to make when your doing this is to use the items .Move method to do all moving and resizing.  You will find it to be significantly faster than setting all the properties separately.  .Move takes Top, Left, Width, and Height so you can do both with it.

Answer (score 2):

If the elements are nog going to change size or position in relation to each other I would probably go for the `PictureBox` approach. I don't see how that would be bad really.

If the controls need to be resized or relocated,  I would (and God knows I used to) write loads of resizing code...

Comment: As I said to slifty, I'll probably wind up doing that approach, either with PictureBox or Frame. I just have zero interest in wasting time doing resizing/recentering code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.functionx.com/vbnet/Lesson08.htm

Look at Control Containers.  As I noted in comment the second solution you described isn't ad hoc - it is organized. UI is all about containers.

You're right in feeling icky about PictureBox, though.

Comment: I'm fine with containers, it's just that VB6 doesn't really provide much in the way of them. You've got PictureBox and Frame. I'll probably wind up going with Frame just because it sounds less... wrong.

Comment: I believe that's what frames are intended for actually.

Comment: I think you're forgetting the UserControl, which can be a fine container.  You can use them as is or use them to create custom control containers (see ControlContainer Property in the VB6 documentation).

Comment: I shall look into it. Forgot to say so when I replied to your previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: Also worth noting is that Frames can't get focus, which isn't critical to this discussion, but does have weight when you consider [this other question I posted a few days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080838/removing-focus-from-all-objects-in-visual-basic-6).

Comment: The link doesn't actually answer the question. It discusses VB.NET, not VB 6. Totally different sets of controls available, with completely different functionality. If the question were about VB.NET, the answer would be simple: use the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties to align the controls on the form. In VB 6, you need to write the resizing code yourself.